# How can I merge the data, values and method sections of the environment panel in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

The environment panel in RStudio is split into data, values and method sections:

[image]

Is there any way to merge them?

---

E.g., in Matlab, variables aren't split:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Do you mean drop the labels "Data" & "Values" or combine all objects into a single object?

Comment: @csgillespie yes

Comment: Which? I give two distinct options

Comment: @csgillespie sorry I misread. I meant drop the labels "Data" & "Values"

Comment: Yes, you need to rewrite large chunks of RStudio. Why do you want to do this? These are very different things in each section and so require a different presentation for each thing. Tell us *why* you want to do that and we might come up with something that is easier than re-writing RStudio.

Comment: @Spacedman Just personal preferences, as the previous Matlab user where variables aren't split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to the "Grid" view (dropdown upper right) I get this slightly different view of all the objects in one list:

[image]

That's an old RStudio - maybe its still doing that?